# Split Column of Semicolon-Separated Values and Duplicate Row with each Value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a data frame with a row of data like this:

```
play_by_play = pd.DataFrame([{
    "players": "Tom Brady; Mike Evans; Tristan Wirfs; Leonard Fournette; Chris Godwin", 
               "down": 1, 
               "to_go": 10,
                "play_type": 'pass',
               "yards_gained": 8,
               "pass_attempt": 1,
               "complete_pass": 1,
               "rush_attempt": 0
              }])
```

I want to keep track of stats while the given players are on the field by using group by and aggregate functions. If I were looking to do this player-by-player, I would use `play_by_play["players"].str.contains("Tom Brady")` and aggregating the data using that filter, but I am looking to automate this. The solution I've landed on is to duplicate rows and have the "players" value split for each row. It would look something like this:

| player | down | to_go | play_type | yards_gained | pass_attempt | complete_pass | rush_attempt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Tom Brady" | 1 | 10 | pass | 8 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| "Mike Evans" | 1 | 10 | pass | 8 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| "Tristan Wirfs" | 1 | 10 | pass | 8 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| "Leonard Fournette" | 1 | 10 | pass | 8 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| "Chris Godwin" | 1 | 10 | pass | 8 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

How could I accomplish this? As I mentioned before, this needs to be pretty scalable, as there are thousands of rows of data. If there's an easier way to group by based on unique values contained in a semicolon-separated column, I'm more than happy to go that route.

Comment: Have you seen [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)? (Don't just look at the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.str.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to make a list of the players then [**`pandas.DataFrame.explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to make multiple rows :

```
play_by_play['players'] = play_by_play['players'].str.split(';')
play_by_play = play_by_play.explode('players').reset_index(drop=True)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(play_by_play)

              players  down  to_go play_type  yards_gained  pass_attempt  complete_pass  rush_attempt
0           Tom Brady     1     10      pass             8             1              1             0
1          Mike Evans     1     10      pass             8             1              1             0
2       Tristan Wirfs     1     10      pass             8             1              1             0
3   Leonard Fournette     1     10      pass             8             1              1             0
4        Chris Godwin     1     10      pass             8             1              1             0
```